# How to convert R date to a number for a given origin date?

Tags: r, date

I want to convert a date to number of days from `00-01-0000` (it's an MATLAB's origin).

e.g.

```
dt_str <- '2016-05-20'
dt <- as.Date(dt_str)
dt_num <- SOME_FUNCTION(dt, origin = '0000-01-01')
```

I am unable to use `as.Date.numeric()`.

Comment: `as.numeric(dt - as.Date("0000-01-01"))`

Comment: or this: `julian(dt, as.Date("0000-01-01"))`

Comment: Thanks. I used `as.numeric(dt - as.Date("0000-01-01")) + 1`.